# Order collection by method value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a model for `Project`:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has many :votes
end
```

And for `Votes`:

```
class Votes < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
end
```

Each `Project` has a number of votes from 1 to 5. To get the average i made a function called `avgVotes` in the `project_controller`.

Now, for my view I can use the `@projects = Project.all` given by the controller, but I want it so that `@projects` is ordered by the value of the `avgVotes` for each `project`.

How can I accomplish this?

Should I order it in the controller or in the view?

Comment: You are doing it wrong. You should calculate averages and order everything inside database engine, that said with SQL. Otherwise you’ll get infinite response time tomorrow.

Comment: First, Rails naming _conventions_ suggest not to use camel-case naming for methods, so you should call your method avg_votes. Second, as @kriskova mentioned, it is not a good idea to write a separate method for ordering because it is much more expensive in comparison to SQL ordering. The fact that you had to write a separate method for sorting shows that you have a flaw in your design.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should keep as much logic out of the view as you can.

So in your controller, you could do something like this:

```
@projects = Project.all.sort_by(&:avgVotes)
```

Keep in mind, that this ordering is not as efficient as:

```
Project.order()
```

because the later orders the results in the db, but the earlier is run in pure ruby which is a lot slower. If you could precalculate these values and store them in the db then you could do this ordering much faster.

Comment: trouble is, `sort` returns an `array`, while `order` returns a `relation`;
may sound irrelevant, but try to explain that to a pagination gem

Answer (score 4):

Your database can perform calculations and Rails comes with corresponding [caluclation methods](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#calculations).

Assuming that `Vote` has an attribute `value` (from 1 to 5), you can find a project's average vote value via:

```
project = Project.find(1)
#=> <Project id:1>
project.votes.average(:value)
# SELECT AVG(`votes`.`value`) FROM `votes` WHERE `votes`.`project_id` = 1
#=> 2.1
```

The above will actually return a `BigDecimal`, I've used a float here because it is easier to read.

But running this query once for every project can be expensive. You can therefore [apply a `GROUP BY` clause](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#group) to find the average values for all projects in a single query:

```
Vote.group_by(:project).average(:value)
# SELECT AVG(`votes`.`value`) AS average_value, project_id AS project_id
# FROM `votes`
# GROUP BY `votes`.`project_id`
```

(Well, actually two queries, because it will also fetch the projects)

It returns a hash with `project => average_value` pairs, something like:

```
{
  <Project id:1> => 2.1,
  <Project id:2> => 4.8,
  <Project id:3> => 3.0,
  # ...
}
```

(again, you'll get `BigDecimal` values, not floats)

You can also let the database order the results from highest average vote value to lowest:

```
Vote.group_by(:project).order('average_value DESC').average(:value)
# SELECT AVG(`votes`.`value`) AS average_value, project_id AS project_id
# FROM `votes`
# GROUP BY `votes`.`project_id`
# ORDER BY average_value DESC
```

Note that the name `average_value` depends on your attribute name. i.e. `average_...`